# UIActivityViewController with NSURL to audio file only shows airdrop

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to use a `UIActivityViewController` to share an audio file (.aac). It is a temporary file that I have written to the sandboxed documents directory.

I pass a `NSURL` in the `initWithActivityItem:` method.

```
[audioData writeToFile:[urlToAudioFile path] options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone error:&error];

UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[urlToAudioFile] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:^{
...
}];
```

When I press the share button it takes a few seconds and the activity sheet pops up with the only option being Airdrop.

How can I get other options like email or iMessage to show up?
Is there a call back method so that I can determine when the "sharing" is finished, so that I can delete the temporary file again?

Is there a way for me to add the audio file without having to write it to disk first? Can't I somehow just pass the `NSData` object?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to share the actual file, then you need to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, it is designed for sharing **entire** files. `UIActivityViewController` is meant for text and maybe an image.

If you need to message your file rather than just open it another app, then consider making a custom `UIActivity` for `UIDocumentInteractionController` and another for Messages and Another for Mail. See `mfmailcomposeviewcontroller` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`

See(Apple Developer): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html